# Create date range from a given table with given dates using mysql query

Tags: mysql, date-range

I want to select data by creating range from three given dates in ascending order and comma separated unique cities that lie between those dates. My table is:

```
  id     city    dob                
------   ------  ------------
 1       x     1993-05-16  
 2       y     1994-07-14  
 3       x     1995-10-18  
 4       z     2008-01-05  
 5       k     2000-01-05  
 6       y     1991-01-05  
 7       y     1992-04-07
```

And i want output like this:

```
count(city)   city    range                
------------  ------  ---------------------
 3             y,x     1991-01-05:1993-05-16  
 3             y,x,k   1994-07-14:2000-01-05  
 1              z      2008-01-05
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: That's a very complex presentation you are asking. I advise you to think of a way to simplify the required output.

Comment: 3 given dates??